# Rolling window forecast in python

Tags: python, regression, forecasting

i asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055520/moving-window-forecasting-with-python) question some days ago but haven't got any response. So I've taken it to myself to do the rolling window manually. My limited grasp on regression forecasting has stumped my progress a bit.

But what I am trying to do is a forecast of n-days ahead based on the information available up to time t-255 (start of the period), and then do another n-day ahead forecasts based on the information from t - 255 + n (until the end of the period), e.g. if n = 5, the window should produce forecasts from 255 to 250, and next window at 250 to 245 and so on.

```
from harrv import mdl, df
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

b0, b1, b2, b3 = mdl.params[0], mdl.params[1], mdl.params[2], mdl.params[3]
rv1, rv5, rv22, mu = df.RV1, df.RV5, df.RV22, b0
walk = sp.stats.invgauss.rvs(mu, size = len(rv1))
pre, p = [], []

def window(seq, n):
    """
    seq -> the sequence over which prediction should be performed

    a rolling window function to calculate n-step ahead prediction"""
    for i in reversed(xrange(0, len(seq))):
        for j in range(1, n):
            pre = b0 + rv1[i] * b1**j + rv5[i] * b2**j + rv22[i] * b3**j + walk[i]           
            p.append(pre)
            i = i + n

    return p
```

Where mdl is my HAC-OLS estimated HAR-RV model with the parameters params, I didnt want the random noise to have too much effect, so I set its MU to be the intercept, which is quite small. 
Im not sure if im doing it right now either, and more pressing, I cant choose a value of n more than 2, cause when I do, this shows:

```
predi = window(rv1, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-480-bbee880e0682> in <module>()
----> 1 predi = window(rv1, 4)

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Python/window_analysis.py in window(seq, n)
     17     for i in reversed(xrange(0, len(seq))):
     18         for j in range(1, n):
---> 19             pre = b0 + rv1[i] * b1**j + rv5[i] * b2**j + rv22[i] * b3**j + walk[i]
     20             p.append(pre)
     21             i = i + n

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    512     def __getitem__(self, key):
    513         try:
--> 514             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    515 
    516             if not np.isscalar(result):

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1458 
   1459         try:
-> 1460             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1461         except KeyError as e1:
   1462             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3113)()

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2844)()

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7255)()

/Users/NiklasLindeke/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7193)()

KeyError: 259
```

The error however, dissapeared when I had the i = i + n in the end of the first for loop, but when I did that, there was alot more appended in p.

I am now though running out of ideas on how to do this.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here? if you want to calculate forecast for every day, week, whatever, you should increment I in the outer loop by one (this is what you seem to try to do). naturally you then get lot of P as you calculate for every day all the forecasts into the future. now with I+N in the inner loop, you end up pointing over the size of one of your variables RVx or walk.

Comment: Please see edit with a more specified description of what I am aiming for.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array with the line "pre = ..."? I do not know the data types you have but it seems to me you create a single integer. This seems odd as you start by definine pre = [] but basically redefine it later. Also, your indexing is off your inner loop adds different values to I and these persist for the outer loop, probably causing the indexing to go wrong (too high).

Comment: so is b0 first prediction, rv1[i]*b1**j the second prediction and so on? I am not familiar with the HAC-xx methods you refer to but seems odd for me to use the same I value for all predictions (why not i+j?).

Comment: The first prediction is the equation plus a noise term since j starts at 1. I cannot let it assume any added information. When it starts to predict at a certain level of i, it need to generate n predictions ahead based on the information available up to time i, and the move along the series until next appropriate stepping point, which would be i + n.

Comment: So if your seq = 255 and n = 5, you end up doing indices of rv[255], rv[255+1], rv[255+1+2], rv[255+1+2+3]. Perhaps you mean to do rv[255], rv[254], ...? Then I would do i = i -1 in the inner loop? Other than that, there should be quite a few values added to P in general. Equal to seq * j, which in this case would be 255*5? If you want to do only 255-250 and 249-245 and so forth, you need to change the outer loop to jump by 5 not by 1.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `seq` except for its length, but you index into several variables that consequently need to have as many elements as the _forward_ movement of your forecast. This makes no sense-- their dimensions cannot depend on how long you want to predict. Plus, I don't know what model you're using but to predict repeatedly, you should be *somehow* using your earlier predictions as part of the system state; either by appending to the time series (if this is an autoregressive model) or at least by using the last prediction in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
for i in reversed(xrange(n, len(seq), n)):
    for j in range(1, n):
        pre = b0 + rv1[i] * b1**j + rv5[i] * b2**j + rv22[i] * b3**j + walk[i]           
        p.append(pre)
        i = i - 1
```

Comment: You might also want to put in range(1, n+1). Otherwise with N = 5 you would get values 1-4, 6-9 and so on. Outer loop might have same issue, depending on your case..

Comment: The issue of it not being able to handle a n > 2 still remains and it only returs 128 rows of data for some reason. However, when I take out the n in the first loop, it returns the appropreate amount of rows.

Comment: how many rows do you expect? 255/5 would be 51. So I guess I still did not quite understand you. Do you get the same error still with too large index?

Comment: No, I expect 255 rows, since "i" moves the dataset from where the model does its prediction, while the n-days ahead is where it appends the p and does that untill 255. But the third argument in the loop is the skip, and it shouldnt skip like that when it already has its i -1.

Comment: If we take seq = 255 and n = 5, the first line creates a list [250,245,240,235, ...]. This means the result list will contain 51 values where the first one is an array for i = 250,249,248,247,246. The inner i -1 is just so it does the 249,248,247,246 inside the outer loop. You want it different?

Comment: I suggest you try code like this separately to get a loop you like: p = []

for i in reversed(range(0, 255, 5)):
    for j in range(1, 5+1):
        p.append(i)
        i -= 1

print(p)

Comment: When the i -1 is in the inside loop, it maked the i go negative, and I think that is causing it to fail, since its out of its index.

For an extensive version on what I am trying to do, here is the same stuff but for Matlab: http://se.mathworks.com/help/econ/rolling-window-estimation-of-state-space-models.html

Comment: if i going negative is the problem, try the edited  version. Basically start the outer loop from N since if you start if you start it from 0, the i-1 will result in negative index for the last iteration.